# Execute a set of stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure to execute all the stored procedures in a schema. This is what I have:

```
ALTER procedure [ALL_IC].[EXECUTE_ICS]
    @sql nvarchar(max) = null, 
    @fa nvarchar(max) = null
as 
begin
    set @sql = ('select (select ''EXEC [IC].['' + b.name + ''];''
                         from sys.procedures b  
                         join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = b.schema_id
                         where s.name = ''IC''
                         for xml path(''''))'
                        ) end 

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Running this selects the string to execute all the stored procedures, but it doesn't actually execute them.

```
EXEC ALL_IC.EXECUTE_ICS
```

How can I actually execute all the stored procedures by running that line of code?

SQL Server 2012

Comment: What if stored procedure require parameters?

Comment: @lad2025 the one's I'm executing don't require parameters.

Comment: This just sounds like a poor design. Blindly running every procedure in a schema sounds like a recipe for disaster. There are so many "what ifs" here.

Comment: @seanlange Can you be more specific? I'm pretty certain with the way I'm using my database that this shouldn't be an issue. But maybe there's just things I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the numerous awful things this brings to mind the actual logic is quite simple. You just need to build a dynamic string and execute it.

Here is a very simple way you can do this.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'EXEC ' + quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(b.name) + ';'
from sys.procedures b
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = b.schema_id
where s.name = 'IC'

select @SQL
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

--EDIT--

Changed slightly so the schema is not hard coded inside the dynamic sql. This way if you want a different schema you just change the schema name and everything else will still work.

--Second Edit--

Changed to use QuoteName instead of hardcoding in the []. This is more flexible and stable.

Comment: Works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure you are not executing any procedures that expect a parameter, I added a little check against the system catalogue `sys.parameters`. The rest is pretty much the same what you were trying to do in your question.

```
Declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);


SELECT @sql = STUFF((SELECT '  Exec ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) +'.'+ QUOTENAME(p.name) + ';  '
                FROM sys.procedures P 
                INNER JOIN sys.schemas S ON P.schema_id = S.schema_id
                WHERE s.name = 'IC' 
                 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                  FROM sys.parameters pm
                                  WHERE p.object_id = pm.object_id)
                 FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'');

Exec sp_executesql @sql
```